# "edit tags" always visible, not just when hovering the tags area

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, 10k-tools

Until recently (probably today) the "edit tags" link appeared (for 10k users who has inline editing) only when hovering the tags area.

However, now it's always visible:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed? I don't think we need both "edit tags" and "edit" always visible.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327730/long-tags-make-things-jump-hide-instead-of-suppress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, this has been implemented recently as a way to fix [the jumping effect when long tags are used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327730/long-tags-make-things-jump-hide-instead-of-suppress). Leaving a blank line under the tags didn't look very nice, so we made the link always visible instead.

**Update:**

Considering how poorly has been this change received, and that the original "jumping" problem affects only a small percent of the questions, it has been undone. We'll try to figure out a better solution.

Comment: This is like fixing a hole in a wall by breaking the wall, i.e. instead of fixing the actual problem, making the problem disappear. Totally disagree with this as it is way worse.

Comment: Whoa, thanks! Good to know our opinions matter. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard What? No! Actually it's just that I didn't want to receive more downvotes ;-)